# Full width menu JavaScript selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

Okay so here is a cut down of what I have so far [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exr1se3u/). Hovering over 'Aviation' brings down the menu. I would like it so that when you open the menu the first menu item is already set to active but also need the current hovered selection to stay selected when they move over the the "Related Links" side of the drop down.

I know very little JS but this is what I have come up with so far to make the menu appear.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".aviation").hover(function() {
    $(".aviation-menu").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".aviation-menu").hover(function() {
    $(".aviation-menu").toggleClass("active");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#top li").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  });
});
```

Any help would massively be appriciated thank you.

Comment: If you remove the class with `$(this).removeClass("active");` with a condition  for example remove it when another `'li'` has become active it should keep the tab open unless another menu item was hovered.

Comment: @biseibutsu Yes this is what I need however my JavaScript knowledge isn't good enough for me to write it myself :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use it like below, I gave the Jsfiddle link at the bottom as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".aviation").hover(function() {
    $(".aviation-menu").toggleClass("active");
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").hover(function() {
    $("li").each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/exr1se3u/2/)

Basically you will be removing all the "active" classes on the other list items when any of them gets hovered, so it will have one active all the time.

Edit: You can also add this `$("li").first().addClass("active");` at the beginning so it will have "Home" as active by default.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the following: There is no "hovering" on mobile devices and what you're doing with JS (adding a class on hover, but actually what you want is a visual change) can be done with CSS, which is nicer in my opinion.

Here is a great example of a pure CSS dropdown menu by Phil Hoyt: http://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/ujHzd

HTML:

```
<h1>Simple Pure CSS Drop Down Menu</h1>
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 2 THIS IS SO LONG IT MIGHT CAUSE AN ISSEUE BUT MAYBE NOT?</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#primary_nav_wrap
{
    margin-top:15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
    display:block;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
    background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
    background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
```